# What is wrong with this js function?

Tags: javascript

Here is a part of my script:

```
function create(panel_id,iframe_source,handle_title) {
 var temp1=document.createElement("a");
 temp1.setAttribute("href","#");
 var attr=document.createAttribute("onClick");
 attr.nodeValue="showPanel(panel_id)";
 temp1.setAttributeNode(attr);
 temp1.className="controller";
 temp1.innerHTML=handle_title;
 div.appendChild(temp1);
}
function showPanel(panel_id) {
 var elem = document.getElementById(panel_id);
 elem.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

And here is the part where I call the first function:

```
<a href="#" onClick="create('test','http://example.com','example')">create</a>
```

When I call it, every element is created correctly and working except for the onClick attribute.I noticed that when I change the function like this:

```
...
attr.nodeValue="showPanel('test')";
...
```

everything is working fine..Can someone tell me what I have done wrong plz?

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: `"showPanel("+panel_id+")";` should work - it may be executing that function where `panel_id` is no longer available as a local variable, use string concatenation to fix that value in place

Comment: You'd better use `temp1.onclick = function() { showPanel(panel_id) };`.

Comment: Or even better, `temp1.addEventListener("click")` /`temp1.attachEvent("onclick")` depending on further interaction with those elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
attr.nodeValue="showPanel(panel_id)";
```

to:

```
attr.nodeValue="showPanel('" + panel_id + "')";
```

Comment: It worked!Thank u very much, but could u please explain this solution?What does "+foo+" do?

Comment: @user2879198 You were passing as parameter your variable name, not the variable value.

Comment: @user2879198 Oh, if it works, you should accept the answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems

1) onClick should be onclick

2) `"showPanel(panel_id)";` should be

```
"showPanel('" + panel_id + "')";
```

try this

```
function create(panel_id,iframe_source,handle_title) {
 var temp1=document.createElement("a");
 temp1.setAttribute("href","#");
 var attr=document.createAttribute("onclick");
 attr.nodeValue="showPanel('" + panel_id + "')";
 temp1.setAttributeNode(attr);
 temp1.className="controller";
 temp1.innerHTML=handle_title;
 div.appendChild(temp1);
}
function showPanel(panel_id) {
 var elem = document.getElementById(panel_id);
 elem.classList.toggle("show");
}
```